# Include DOM with Jquery FancyBox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to use the Fancy Box 2 plugin (fancyapps.com).

All is well except I cannot figure out how to include a DOM element properly.

I am calling this after a form submit that is returning information via ajaxform and validation. documentation says to use the following for dom.

```
//DOM element:

$.fancybox( $("#inline"), {
    title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

Now if i create an id on the page in a div it doesn't pull it. Also the div shows.

I tried using the other method (custom object)

```
$.fancybox({
    href: 'example.jpg',
    title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

and it does not seem to work with php files. I am trying to populate the lightbox with information from a php file but i get error loading content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `ajax()` in here.

As I look into the FancyBox plugin, it does support ajax.

```
$("#various3").fancybox({
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        data: 'mydata=test'
    }
});​
```

**HTML**

`<li><a id="various3" href="/data/login.php">Ajax - passing custom data</a></li>`

All of these where based on its demo's source code. [Demo page](http://fancybox.net/home) & [http://fancybox.net/js/](http://fancybox.net/js/web.js?m=20100203).

**UPDATE**:

I did a quick test using [fancyBox version 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), pertaining your question.

I achieve to pull the ajax contents:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        title: 'Custom Title'
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="ajax.txt">Show content</a>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I've noticed that the important part in here is naming your class to `class="fancybox fancybox.ajax"`.

Comment: yea.. i didn't see that in the documentation.. i looked everywhere.. that seems to be for version 1. i use version 2 @ http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/  i will look into it and see if it works for this version as well

Comment: this also is based on a link. Im calling it from directly in my script.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that your missing your selector to the id of the picture.

ie: $("#inline")

```
$.fancybox( $("#inline"), {
  href: 'example.jpg',
  title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

or

```
$("#inline").fancybox( {
  href: 'example.jpg',
  title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

you could also use a class instead of an id to match against.

```
$(".inline").fancybox(
  href: 'example.jpg',
  title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating (via php) a `div` with `id="inline"`, then this script should do the trick

```
$.fancybox({
 href  : "#inline",
 title : 'Custom Title'
});
```

I assume that you will be calling this script as a callback after you populated the `div` (within another script perhaps) but you didn't provide details of how fancybox will be fired.

Comment: It is being fired after form validation with Jquery validation using one of the methods above. HTML works fine just not php